# Under the U.S.'s Copyright Law, is it an act of copyright infringement if we changed the color of another artist's image to black and white?

Tags: color

Under the U.S.'s Copyright Law, would it be an act of copyright infringement if we were to change the color of another artist's image to black and white?

The answer to this question is provided [below by Scott](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/17250/12112).
For further information, please check out [graphicsman post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/17251/12112), which is also provided below.

This question was asked to make it clear for those who may think that by changing the color or the size of another artist's work, you did not violate the U.S Copyright Law, which is not true.

Instead of trying to manipulate another artist's image to entitle ourselves as the "original" owner, the right and proper action is to request the permission to use it.

Comment: Bear in mind that (a) SE cannot provide definitive legal advice; (b) copyright law differs between countries -- and you haven't mentioned which you are interested in. Nonetheless, [Scott's answer](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/17250/4215) is good general advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It's a derivative work and is infringement assuming the original has all rights reserved.

Comment: What if we were to re-size the image?

Comment: It doesn't matter, it's still their work.

Comment: That does not matter. If the rights are reserved there is **nothing** you can do to allow for a derivative work.

Comment: If you are wanting to use their work contact them and get written permission.

Comment: @CLearner See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barack_Obama_%22Hope%22_poster#Origin_and_copyright_issues) article for a famous example of derivative work in copyright law

Answer (score 1):

have a look at this in regards to [copyright](http://www.copyright.gov/title17/92chap13.html)

> > § 1301. Designs protected2
>
> (a) Designs protected. —
>
> (1) In general. — The designer or other owner of an original design of
>   a useful article which makes the article attractive or distinctive in
>   appearance to the purchasing or using public may secure the protection
>   provided by this chapter upon complying with and subject to this
>   chapter.
>
> (2) Vessel features.—The design of a vessel hull, deck, or combination
>   of a hull and deck, including a plug or mold, is subject to protection
>   under this chapter, notwithstanding section 1302(4).
>
> (3) Exceptions.—Department of Defense rights in a registered design
>   under this chapter, including the right to build to such registered
>   design, shall be determined solely by operation of section 2320 of
>   title 10 or by the instrument under which the design was developed for
>   the United States Government.
>
> (b) Definitions. — For the purpose of this chapter, the following
>   terms have the following meanings:
>
> (1) A design is “original” if it is the result of the designer's
>   creative endeavor that provides a distinguishable variation over prior
>   work pertaining to similar articles which is more than merely trivial
>   and has not been copied from another source.
>
> (2) A “useful article” is a vessel hull or deck, including a plug or
>   mold, which in normal use has an intrinsic utilitarian function that
>   is not merely to portray the appearance of the article or to convey
>   information. An article which normally is part of a useful article
>   shall be deemed to be a useful article.
>
> (3) A “vessel” is a craft —
>
> (A) that is designed and capable of independently steering a course on
>   or through water through its own means of propulsion; and
>
> (B) that is designed and capable of carrying and transporting one or
>   more passengers.
>
> (4) A ‘hull’ is the exterior frame or body of a vessel, exclusive of
>   the deck, superstructure, masts, sails, yards, rigging, hardware,
>   fixtures, and other attachments.
>
> (5) A “plug” means a device or model used to make a mold for the
>   purpose of exact duplication, regardless of whether the device or
>   model has an intrinsic utilitarian function that is not only to
>   portray the appearance of the product or to convey information.
>
> (6) A “mold” means a matrix or form in which a substance for material
>   is used, regardless of whether the matrix or form has an intrinsic
>   utilitarian function that is not only to portray the appearance of the
>   product or to convey information.
>
> (7) A ‘deck’ is the horizontal surface of a vessel that covers the
>   hull, including exterior cabin and cockpit surfaces and exclusive of
>   masts, sails, yards, rigging, hardware, fixtures, and other
>   attachments.